# Unable to change value of method variable inside if statement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def a():
  no_user = False
  
  number_of_users = # gets number of users from db
  
  if number_of_users == 0:
    no_user = True

  if no_user:
    print("no users in db")
  else:
    print(number_of_users)
```

when above method is run, it never prints "no user in db", even when there are no users in db. the variable `no_user` in if block warns that it is not used.

I understand this is because of scope and this could have been solved if the `no_user` variable was global instead of method variable. But in this case, I need it to be inside method, and change to True when there are no users in db.

Comment: I don't see any problem. Is this the actual code? local var `no_user` is definitely updatable anywhere inside a function/method

Comment: "I understand this is because of scope " why do you say that? Almost certainly it isn't an issue of scope. Your logic doesn't make sense, why would there be no users if `number_of_users > 0`...? There would be no users if `number_of_users == 0`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga still, there shouldn't be an "unused var" warning on `no_user`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes you are correct, I cannot post actual code. All this is handwritten. corrected.

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov found the issue. it was because i placed a return statement under `no_user = True`. Hence the warning. My bad.

Comment: @RajyawardhanSinghPanwar ok, *regardless* you can very clearly test it out for yourself by assigning an actual number, running the function, using a different number, and seeing that you can in fact change the value. Until you can provide a [mcve] this question is off-topic

Comment: @RajyawardhanSinghPanwar Why not just do `if getNumberOfUsers() < 1:` or similar. Means that the result of the query to the database is directly feeding the if statement rather than going through some other unnecessary code.

Comment: @scotty3785 thanks for the suggestion. But there are other processing steps done based on the value of flag.

Comment: @RajyawardhanSinghPanwar In which case use `if number_of_users < 1:` instead. There is little point having another variable just to set a boolean.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

i guess, you should modify part as below:

```
  if number_of_users > 0:
    no_user = False
```

since if number_of_users > 0, then there are users and no_user should be false

Comment: You just reversed the logic... It should work just the same as it is now. If the number of users is `0` then `no_user = True`... What's wrong with that?

Comment: However, just to be sure, I would do `if number_of_users == 0 and number_of_users == -1` in case database is somehow not exist or program is unable to read from file or create list, then number_of_users can return -1

Comment: I didn't see the question was edited. Sorry... Anyway the answer now is not relevant. Also, `if number_of_users == 0 and number_of_users == -1` makes no sense... Maybe `... or ...`

Comment: yes, it should be `or` for sure. checking "not exist" conditions should be a good programming habit.